# Show that the linear transformation $T:V\to W$ defined by $T(x,y)=(5x+7y,2x+3y)$ is bijective.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ defined by $T((x,y))=(5x+7y,2x+3y)$, we need to show that $T$ is bijective.

I am not sure whether I need to use the rank-nullity theorem and if so, how.

I would appreciate a good hint to put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The transformation $T$ is represented by the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5&7\\2&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

that is invertible. So...

Comment: This is helpful! This means that I can find a matrix that represents $T^{-1}$ and create an inverse function? If I can find an inverse function, that means that $T$ is bijective.

Comment: Yes.  And this fact is linked to the rank nullity theorem because the kernel of $T$ contains only the zero vector.

Comment: Okay, I found the inverse matrix by the following: $\left[{\begin{array}{cccc}
    5 & 7 & 1 & 0\\
    2 & 3 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{array}}\right]=
 \left[{\begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 3 & -7\\
    0 & 1 & -2 & 5\\
    \end{array}}\right]$ but I am unsure of how to write $T^{-1} as a function?

Comment: Your inverse matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}3&-7\\-2&5 \end{bmatrix}$  so the inverse transformation is $(x,y) \rightarrow (3x-7y,-2x+5y)$

Answer (score 1):

Constructing an inverse is great (and easy!), but I prefer the following viewpoint:

A function is bijective if and only if it is both injective and surjective. It follows from the rank nullity theorem (why?) that a linear transformation between two vector spaces of the same finite dimension is bijective if and only if it is injective if and only if it is surjective. Thus you only need to show either injectivity or surjectivity. Injectivity is probably the easiest because a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ is injective if and only if its kernel
$$
\ker(T) = \{v\in V \mid Tv=0\}
$$
equals $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about showing that $\ker(T)=\{0\}$ but wasn't sure how to go about doing it- this makes sense.

Comment: @MathStudent1324 Suppose $T(x,y)=0$. Then $5x+7y=0$ and $2x+3y=0$. Use this to deduce $x=y=0$. (You can use matrices and elimination or just get $x=(-7y)/5$ from the first equation and substitute this into the second. Alternatively you could write each equation as $y=(-5/7)x$ and $y=(-2/3)x$ and observe that these two lines will only intersect at the origin.)

Answer (score 0):

By the rank-nullity theorem a transformation is injective if the dimension of the nullspace is zero and because the dimension of $V$ and $W$ are the same this is sufficient to prove invertibility.  Write the transformation in matrix notation as

$T((x,y))=\begin{bmatrix}
5&7\\2&3
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}$

and now there are several properties of the matrix \begin{bmatrix}
5&7\\2&3
\end{bmatrix} we can exploit to show it's invertible. The determinant is $1$ which is not zero so it's invertible. If we row reduce the matrix we get \begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\0&1
\end{bmatrix} and since all the pivots are non-zero so it's invertible. You can calculate the inverse explicitly as \begin{bmatrix}3&-7\\-2&5 \end{bmatrix} and show that it is a two-sided inverse to prove it's bijective without using the rank-nullity theorem as well although it is the most computationally expensive choice.